# Specific example of using angular element within Sitefinity content

Tags: angular, sitefinity

Looking for a simple, complete example of including an angular element within a Sitefinity page. [Any idea how can I add an Angular4 application as a content page in sitefinity cms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45490634/any-idea-how-can-i-add-an-angular4-application-as-a-content-page-in-sitefinity-c) hints at it, but is short on detail. Thanks!

Comment: What exact issue are you facing?

Comment: I can create the .js files that constitute an Angular element library; just not sure the mechanics to get a component to show up within Sitefinity - e.g. where to place the .js files, how to references them from within Sitefinity's infrastructure, what sort of Sitefinity component to use to reference the library. Thanks!

Comment: To make the component show up in Sitefinity, you need to create a page widget, see https://www.progress.com/documentation/sitefinity-cms/create-widgets-mvc In the View of the widget you place your html and js code. Then drag the widget on a page

Answer (score 0):

I have an example that uses AngularJS version 1.x. In my case, I needed to display credit card rates on a page, using AngularJS to pull the rates from a web service.

**Step 1**: Create custom MVC widget. In theory, you could even use a content block to hold the markup in step 2 instead of a custom widget.

File: SitefinityWebApp/MVC/Controllers/FeaturedRateController.cs

```
namespace Website.Mvc.Controllers
{
    [ControllerToolboxItem(Name = "FeaturedRate", Title = "Featured Rate", SectionName = "...", CssClass = "sfNewsViewIcn sfMvcIcn")]
    public class FeaturedRateController : BaseController<FeaturedRateViewModel>
    {
        public override ActionResult Index()
        {
            // Some code is omitted to set model properties.
            return View("Default", Model);
        }
    }
}
```

**Step 2**: Create widget view.

File: SitefinityWebApp/MVC/Views/FeaturedRate/Default.cshtml

```
@model Website.Mvc.Models.FeaturedRateViewModel

<!-- Some markup is omitted -->
<div>
    <featured-rate rateId="@Model.RateId" rateType="@Model.RateType">...</featured-rate>
</div>
```

**Step 3**: Create AngularJS component. I like to keep my javascript files in the same directory as the razor view, so that I don't have to jump around alot in the file explorer while I'm working on a feature.

File: SitefinityWebApp/MVC/Views/FeaturedRate/featured-rate.component.js

```
(function () {
    angular
        .module('mymodule')
        .component('featuredRate', {
            template: '<span class="rate">{{vm.rate.value}}</span><span class="units">{{vm.rate.units}}</span>',
            transclude: true,
            controllerAs: 'vm',
            controller: featuredRate,
            bindings: {
                rateid: '@',
                ratetype: '@'
            }
        });

    featuredRate.$inject = ['$http'];

    function featuredRate($http) {
        this.$onInit = function () {
            var vm = this;

            getCurrentRate(vm.ratetype, vm.rateid)
                .then(function (response) {
                    vm.rate = parseResponse(vm.ratetype, response.data);
                }, function (response) {
                    console.log(response.status);
                    vm.rate = {
                        value: '...',
                        units: ''
                    };
                });
        };

        function getCurrentRate(type, id) {
            // implementation omitted.
        }
    }
})();
```

I'm using a Gulp task to concatenate all of my js files / angular components to the file /assets/dist/js/main.js. Then, I load in that file from my default template.

File: SitefinityWebApp/ResourcePackages/Bootstrap4/MVC/Views/Layouts/Base.cshtml

```
@Html.Script(Url.Content("~/assets/dist/js/main.js"), true, "bottom")
```